# Most recent jump probability

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Assume I have two independent Poisson processes with respective parameters$$ \sim\text{Poisson}(\alpha_1),\sim \text{Poisson}(\alpha_2)$$ that I observe over a time interval $[0,t].$

What is the probability then that the latest jump on this interval was done by the second process?

So what I am looking for is something like an equation that explicitly states this probability. Does anybody know if there is anything like that? My problem is that this event that I want to describe with a probability is too abstract for me to catch.

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Do you know anything about the relation of the two processes? (Are they independent or, in some way, correlated, or...?)

Comment: @saz oh yes, they are independent

Comment: @saz do you have an idea how this could be done?

Comment: $\frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_1+\alpha_2}$. It's a standard result for Poisson/minimum of two exponentially distributed variables.

Comment: @A.S. Could you elaborate how this is related to the OP's question? (I end up with something different, but my calculation is rather lengthy and perhaps there is some mistake in it.)

Comment: @saz Start counting from time $t$ backwards. First arrival of each process is governed by an exponential random variable with respective $\alpha_i$ parameter. $P(\exp(\alpha_2)<\exp(\alpha_1))=\frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_1+\alpha_2}$.

Comment: @A.S. I see, thanks. So there is something off with the signs in my calculations... but anyway, your solution is much cleverer & easier. :)

Comment: @saz To formulate this better, *any* point from a combined process belongs to the second process with the probability given. This formulation leads to a very easy derivation.

Comment: @saz thank you for helping me. Actually, I wanted to solve the following exercise: Given two independent Poisson processes $N_0,N_1$ with parameters $\beta, \delta.$ Then we define a process $X$ on $\{0,1\}$ jumping from $0$ to $1$ if $X$ is in $0$ and $N_0$ jumps. Then I am supposed to show that the transfer matrix is given by $\begin{matrix} -\beta && \beta \\ \delta &&\ -\delta \end{matrix}$

Comment: @saz now the thing is that I thought for instance $P_t(0,0)=P^0(X(t)=0|N_0 \text{ jumps}) P^0(N_0 \text{ jumps}) + P^0(X(t)=0|N_0 \text{ does not jump})P_0(N_0 \text{ does not jump}). $ Then $P^0(X(t)=0|N_0 \text{ does not jump})=1$ cause if you don't jump with $N_0$ you'll stay in 0. The probability that you don't jump in the time-interval $[0,t]$ with $N_0$ is $e^{- \beta t}$. The event that you end up in $0$ and $N_0$ jumps is the same as the one that $N_1$ jumps most recently (viewed from $t$), as this assures that you end up in $0.$

Comment: But something is wrong here, as the transition probability $p_t(0,0)$ for this Q-matrix is given by $p_t(0,0) = \frac{\delta}{\beta+ \delta} + \frac{\beta}{\beta+ \delta}e^{-t (\beta+ \delta)}.$ This is certainly different from what I got, which would be:

Comment: @saz $P_t(0,0)= \frac{\delta}{\beta + \delta } (1- e^{-\beta t})+1 \cdot e^{-\beta t} $ as I got from the law of total expectation and your help. Do you see the error?

Comment: So again $P^0(X(t)=0|N_0 \text{ jumps}) = P^0(N_1 \text{ jumps most recently}) = \frac{\delta}{\beta + \delta}.$ $P(N_0 \text{ jumps})=1- e^{-\beta t}$. $P^0(X(t)=0|N_0 \text{ does not jump})=1$ and $P(N_0 \text{ does not jump})= e^{- \beta t}.$ Could you help me finding my error?